# C# Equivalent of Python's itertools.chain

Tags: c#

What (if any) is the C# equivalent of Python's itertools.chain method?

Python Example:

```
l1 = [1, 2]
l2 = [3, 4]
for v in itertools.chain(l1, l2):
    print(v)
```

Results:
1
2
3
4

Note that I'm not interested in making a new list that combines my first two and then processing that.  I want the memory/time savings that itertools.chain provides by not instantiating this combined list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Enumerable.Concat` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx))

```
var l1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2 }; 
var l2 = new List<int>() { 3, 4 }; 

foreach(var item in Enumerable.Concat(l1, l2))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString()) 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do the same on C# by using the [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) extension method from [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx):

```
l1.Concat(l2)
```

LINQ uses a deferred execution model, so this won't create a new list.

Answer (score 1):

I've started building my own c# equivalent of itertools.  Here is what I came up with for chain.  Nice and succinct and keeps some of the Python charm.  Here are two implementations of Chain.  It seems the compiler can't distinguish between the call signatures, so use the one that best suites you.

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> Chain<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> collection)
    {
        foreach (var innerCollection in collection)
        {
            foreach (var item in innerCollection)
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Chain<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] collection)
    {
        foreach (var innerCollection in collection)
        {
            foreach (var item in innerCollection)
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
```